# How to pause the javascript execution

Tags: javascript

When java-script encounter 'Windows.Confirm('Some Test'),It does not execute next line codes, until user press either okay or cancel button

form example:-

```
<script>
var i=10;
windows.confirm('Some Text'); //execution pause,untill user press either okay or cancel button
console.log(i);
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me how the `window.confirm()` method works.
Does it update any flag value in windows ,which pause the execution.

Comment: It's an internal implementation detail. No, you cannot replicate this within Javascript code, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks,There must be some ways,I am looking forward an answer

Comment: Ways for what? **YOU**, the developer, cannot stop JS execution programatically. There are no ways to "stop" javascript, but there are ways to write JS programs that make it _appear_ the execution stopped. Why don't you ask the question about the actual problem you have instead of how `confirm` works?

Comment: You'd best describe what you are trying to do... But you do not want to stop javascript execution, that is for sure. The only way you can really block it is work something like while(true)

Comment: Guys ,If you have the answer please reply,Otherwise please ignore the questios

Comment: ?? The answer is: You can't, and there's no work-around for the exact functionality of modal windows. You can only emulate the action with timers and callback functions.

Comment: People can explain it to you but no one can understand it *for* you. Good luck with whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly `window.confirm` works is an internal implementation detail of the specific browser and irrelevant to you, since you cannot in any way replicate what it does from userland Javascript code.